# How to connect to SQL Server through proxy server

Tags: sql-server, networking, proxy, database-connection

Is it possible to connect to SQL Server server through proxy (http) using SQLSERVER oledb provider?

How can I specify proxy address and port in connection string if it's possible?

What nonstandard methods to bypass proxy you'd recommend if it's not possible?

Comment: I've solved it using custom tcp tunneling application, which allows to bypass proxy server.

Comment: could you describe how exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This article seems specific to MS ISA servers, but the theory may hold.

2008

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190801.aspx

2005

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190801(SQL.90).aspx

---

edit:

Perhaps a sql 2005 web service would fit your needs?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345140(SQL.90).aspx

It won't give you normal odbc functionality though.  You shouldn't be exposing your SQL server to the internet btw.

Also, see comment.

Comment: Thanks. But I've got different situation here, SQLSERVER is public server on the Internet, and I'm going to Internet through http proxy server. Also it'd be great to connect with minimum (none) modifications to proxy configuration.

Comment: And I'm voted down why??  

But concerning your comment, I would think you need to make a modification to allow traffic to your sql server on a specific port using tcp.  SQL does not do http, unless you are going to use a webservice.

Comment: Nobody said to expose your SQL server to the public.  I said not to in the answer.  The articles I link to note you can restrict connections to certain clients.

Comment: Do you have an example connection string? I have a proxy setup but I need to figure out how to do the connection string.